# Is X509 certificate qualifed?

Tags: c#, certificate, x509certificate, ocsp

I need to check revocation status of this certificate with OCSP server. So I get "good" status for every CA card that I insert in card reader , but that's not right. I need to get "good" for those , which are activated by Government for signing,and get "Revoked" for those,which aren't activated for digitally signing.
Which parameter should I check to get that?
This is the code. Org.Bouncy.Castle

```
List<string> finalOcspServers = new List<string>();
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate clientCert = client.ToBouncyX509Certificate();
Org.BouncyCastle.X509.X509Certificate issuerCert = issuer.ToBouncyX509Certificate();
FirmaXadesNet.Clients.OcspClient ocsp = new Clients.OcspClient();
string certOcspUrl = ocsp.GetAuthorityInformationAccessOcspUrl(issuerCert);
   if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(certOcspUrl))
                {
                    finalOcspServers.Add(certOcspUrl);
                }
foreach (var ocspUrl in finalOcspServers)
                {
                    // ես եմ փոխել-> այ ստեղ նայել ուսումնասիրել
                    byte[] resp = ocsp.QueryBinary(issuerCert, clientCert, ocspUrl);

                    FirmaXadesNet.Clients.CertificateStatus status = ocsp.ProcessOcspResponse(resp);

                    if (status == FirmaXadesNet.Clients.CertificateStatus.Revoked)
                    {
                        throw new Exception("Revoked certificate");
                    }
                    else if (status == FirmaXadesNet.Clients.CertificateStatus.Good)
                    {
                        Org.BouncyCastle.Ocsp.OcspResp r = new Org.BouncyCastle.Ocsp.OcspResp(resp);

                        check_OCSP = true;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: You have two choices 1) Add only the Certificates into the user stores for the encryption modes you want to use. 2) Add a callback method to check the encryption mode.  See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/bb408523(v%3Dexchg.140)  The Validate method does a Virtual connection to a local server.  The server as part of authentication returns a list a certificate names which are checked against the certificate stores and passes if any certificate validates.  The callback ,method allow you to restrict the list of acceptable certificates.

Comment: But How? I am getting x509certificate2 from digitally signed XML document. And then I need to get revocation status of that certificate

Comment: Is status in the text of the certificate?

Comment: No. But why this part is returning "good" status.FirmaXadesNet.Clients.CertificateStatus status = ocsp.ProcessOcspResponse(resp);

Comment: I do not know the FirmaXadesNet library.  I do know TLS.  The server passes to the client in a TLS Certificate message a list of certificates names that are acceptable.  Then the client checks the user certificate stores for a matching certificate.  The status indicates a matching certificate.  You can see the certificate block if you use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler.If you want to limit which certificates are used you either have to modify the server to remove unwanted certificates from the list it sends to client, or have client add additional checks to verify the type of certificate.

Answer (score 0):

OCSP returns the revocation status. If you have further requirements like an allow-list of certificates (I don't know what you mean by activated) or a certain [EKU Code Signing](http://www.oid-info.com/get/1.3.6.1.5.5.7.3.3) you have to implement that on your own.

**EDIT**: Activation, in terms of PKI, then means they create certificates or load certificates on smart cards. [OCSP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6960) does not provide you the information which EKU is used. OCSP knows the issuer, the serial number and the revocation status. If on the opposite deactivation means revoke a certificate, OCSP could be used to check the validity. But as you told there are other certificates (*So I get "good" status for every*) and you want to distinguish the ones that have a EKU of CodeSigning you need to check the EKU in you code and OCSP cannot do that for you.

Comment: Our company activates those ID cards for digitally signing,whose owners pay for them. They said,that all information about activated certificates is in OCSP server.You are right.That is an allow-list,but they said that all information is in OCSP server.